# how check null in angularjs $http

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json

i have data json schedule flight , but the json does not show all information. It's just returning null some data and all data show null is already existing. i want check my data if there null , i post my same question but his different about jquery .

short code :

```
nameApp.controller('bgwCtrl', function($scope, $http,$interval,labeltext,$timeout,$ionicLoading, $ionicPopup,arrivecss) {

  $scope.loading = true;
  // Setup the loader
  $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Loading',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 0
  });

     $scope.reload = function () {

    $http.get("v1/airport.json?code=bgw")
    .then(function(response) {

    $timeout(function () {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  $scope.labeltext=labeltext;
  $scope.check=arrivecss;
   $scope.time= response.data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.timestamp;

       var dailyData = response.data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data;
         console.log(response.data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data);

            $scope.dailyForecast = [null];

            for(var i=0; i<25; i++)
            {
                 $scope.dailyForecast[i] = {callsin: dailyData[i].flight.identification.id,
                                            callsign: dailyData[i].flight.identification.number.default,
                                            statu: dailyData[i].flight.status.generic.status.text,
                                            airline: dailyData[i].flight.airline.code.iata,
                                            from: dailyData[i].flight.airport.origin.position.region.city,
                                            timear: dailyData[i].flight.time.scheduled.arrival,
                                            generic: dailyData[i].flight.status.text,
                                            ident: dailyData[i].flight.identification.number.default,
                                            timearrvie: dailyData[i].flight.time.estimated.arrival,
                                            timearr: dailyData[i].flight.status.generic.eventTime.local,
                                            model: dailyData[i].flight.aircraft.model.code,
                                            icon: dailyData[i].flight.status.icon,
                                            winir: dailyData[i].flight.airline.name,




                                            };


            }   

          console.log(response)
  }, 2000);
             return response;

    });
///response end///
  function switchEstimated(){
     $scope.show=!$scope.show;
  }

  $interval(switchEstimated,3000);
     $timeout(function(){
      $scope.reload();
    },30000)

  };
  ///reload end///
  $scope.reload();
      $scope.loading = false;

});
```

[my data json](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=08ce07c07754ce6ccf5c4caf39f8ac92)

Error: `departures[i].flight.airport.origin.position is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with what you are looking for. I see that the line

```
departures[i].flight.airport.origin.position
```

Which you say that it gives `undefined` should be

```
dailyData[i].flight.airport.origin.position
```

As you have stored the `data` array in `dailyData`

Comment: still same problem

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error `departures[i].flight.airport.origin.position is undefined` because actually its undefined. If you look at the structure of your JSON data you will find:

```
departures:{item:{},page:{},timestamp:value,data:[]}
```

So you have to change your call with following:

```
departures.data[i].flight.airport.origin.destination.position
```

Comment: still same problem